# CSS transform and transition

Tags: css

I have a rectangle created in CSS, added a transition so when I hover, the shape shrink and disappear:

```css
.shapeB{
 background-color: #FFCC00;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 -webkit-transition:all 1s;
}

.shapeB:hover{
 height:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shapeB"></div>
```

But the fact that it shrinks up is not what I want, I want it to shrink going down. Trying to stimulate liquid being consumed. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
 .box{ 
    position:absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    left:50px;
    top:50px; 
 }

.shapeB{
  background-color: #FFCC00;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  -webkit-transition:all 1s;
}

.shapeB:hover{
   height:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<div class="shapeB"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I still couldn't get it to work :( So here's my CSS now:
    .logo{
 background-color: #ffffff;
 width:198px;
 height:253px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 z-index: 999;}

    .logoF{
 background: url(images/cut-out.svg) no-repeat;
 position: absolute;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;}

    .logoB{
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 background-color: #FFCC00;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 99px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 99px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 -webkit-transition:all 1s;}

    .logo:hover > .logoB{
 height:0;}

Comment: Got it working, I think it was somehow cached before so it doesn't seems to work. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You could somehow missplace the div `100px` down, to give that impression. Something like this:

```css
.shapeB{
    background-color: #FFCC00;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
 -webkit-transition:all 1s;
}

.shapeB:hover{
    height:0px;
    top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shapeB"></div>
```

Comment: The problem is once I take "Position:relative" out, it doesn't work anymore. In my case, my div has to be an absolute.
My whole structure what like this: Main DIV with 2 DIVs position absolute right on top of each other. One is a transparent svg while the back div is a solid color, when mouseover, the back DIV (solid color) will transform to none, stimulate a glass of liquid being drank.